# nonlinear system: properties of solutions

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have a nonlinear system of equations which I'm struggling to solve and actually do not have much hope to find an explicit solution. I do not need to solve it; but I want to prove a property of the solution of this system, namely 'monotonicity' of the combination of solution components depending on the parameter.
The system is:
$$
    \begin{align}
    x_1&=(\hat{d}_1+q_1)(q_1+q_2+pq_1)\\
    x_2&=(\hat{d}_2+q_2)(q_1+q_2)\\
    q_1&=\bar{d}_1-\Bigl( k_1 \sqrt{d^2_1+x_1} + \frac{x_1}      {x_1+x_2}k_0\sqrt{d^2+(x_1+x_2)}+\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2}k_0d\Bigl)\\
    q_2&=\bar{d}_2-\Bigl( k_2 \sqrt{d^2_2+x_2} + \frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2}k_0\sqrt{d^2+(x_1+x_2)}+\frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2}k_0d\Bigl)
    \end{align}
$$
where $(x_1, x_2, q_1, q_2)$ are unknowns, $p$ is a parameter and all others are constants:

$k_0, \ k_1, \ k_2, \ d_1, \ d_2$ are unrelated and 
$$ 
\begin{align} 
d&=d_1+d_2\\
\hat{d_i}&=2d_i\\ 
\bar{d_i}&=\bigl(2/(k_0+k_i-1)+2k_0+k_i\bigl)d_i
\end{align}
$$

The statement (which is a hypothesis but I believe it should be true) I'm trying to prove is:
$$ \frac{x_1}{k_1+k_0-1}+\frac{x_2}{k_2+k_0-1} \quad \text{   increases as     } p \text{     increases}$$

Any ideas would be very helpful. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For clarity, you should mention that all the $\hat{d}_i$ and $\bar{d}_i$ and $d$ are unrelated -- or specify how they are related.

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't mention this indeed. updated the post now.

Comment: very sorry there was a typo in the initial question, now fixed. hope nobody wasted time on solving the wrong system!